# How to use MinimalLayout.exe for Visual Studio

Tags: download, visual-studio-2022, offline

Can someone tell me:

1. What is the expected output of "MinimalLayout.exe generate"?
2. Why is nothing being updated or generated?  (Assuming that a file is supposed to updated or created)

"MinimalLayout.exe generate" doesn't seem to do anything.  MinimalLayout.exe displays data on the console but nothing else.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Start with Visual Studio v17.0.4
2. Export configuration (20240229.vsconfig)
3. Move 20240229.vsconfig from Air-Gap computer to Internet facing computer
4. Run: `vs_Professional.exe --layout C:\VSLayout --config "C:\20240229.vsconfig"`
5. This gets all of my packages.
6. Run: `MinimalLayout.exe preview --targetLocation c:\VSLayout\ --productIds Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional --baseVersion 17.0.4 --targetVersion 17.9.2 --languages en-US`
7. Run: `MinimalLayout.exe generate --targetLocation c:\VSLayout\ --productIds Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional --baseVersion 17.0.4 --targetVersion 17.9.2 --languages en-US`

At step 6, the console say that there are 1000+ new or updated items.
At step 7, I expect a file or updates to my packages, but nothing happens.  The messages on the console are positive; claims to be successful.